# Microsoft Edge : Need help, I need the drop-down to stay opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Am using windows 8.1 :

In microsoft edge browser, Inside the menu drop-down on dragging the textarea scroll, It closes the drop-down automatically.

I need the menu drop-down to stay open.

CSS code :

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    .menu li .dropdwn { display:none; }
    .menu li.active .dropdwn { display:block; }
</style>
```

HTML code :

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        Link 1
        <div class="dropdwn">
            <textarea>
                Some text
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        Link 2
        <div class="dropdwn">
            <!-- DropDown HTML -->
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('.menu li').click(trigAction);
    }); 
    $(document).on("tap mouseup", function (e) {
        if($(".menu li").hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active'); 
        }
    });
    function trigAction(e) {
        e.preventDefault();     
        $(this).parent().find('li').removeClass('active');

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
            // Add action code.
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            // Remove action code.
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }       
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the Edge browser?  You may be using IE11, since the Edge browser wasn't introduced until Windows 10.

Comment: As Ryan stated, Microsoft Edge (the Browser) was released to Windows 10; so it's likely you're using Internet Explorer (perhaps in Edge mode), or you're streaming the Edge engine in the IE shell via http://remote.modern.ie. Either way, I was unable to reproduce the reported issue ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5k7vcug/)) with either Microsoft Edge on Windows 10, Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10, or Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: @RyanHayes i have checked in the live emulator provided by microsoft... and some other systems as well ... its working the same ...